# Value of ListObject.DataBodyRange.Cells(x,y) resulting a different value than the real one

Tags: excel, vb6

I want to extract the currency value inserted in the (x,y) cell of the listObject - table which is in my excel work sheet. 
Values inserted in the table with below formats :

> Cell style = "Currency"
>   Number Format  = "*-$* #,##0*-;-$* #,##0_-;*-$* "-"??*-;*-@*-"

The problem I got in here is when I extract the value of the cell, it is giving an another value.

If number is 213, my code

```
dim mobjtbl_base as ListObject
dim cur as Currency

cur = mobjtbl_base.DataBodyRange.Cells(y, x)
```

here cur = 212.50

Please anybody tell me how to extract the exact amount in the cell.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably displayed as `213` due to the number-format but the actual value is `212.5`

Comment: What does this have to do with VB6? Did you mean VBA?